# GROUP BY HAVING Logic not working (min/max dates)

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have 2 tables: Apples and Oranges. Apples has a FirstDate column, and a LastDate column per ApplesID. Oranges has just one Date column with multiple records (Occurrences) per ApplesID which can each have different dates. Neither technically ingests into the other, but the logic is that the min(Oranges.Date) = Apples.FirstDate, and max(Oranges.Date) = Apples.LastDate per ApplesID. I am just querying to see where the above logic isn't true.

Below is my query attempting to find this, but when I run it and I am seeing results where the above logic holds and doesn't hold. Results where the logic holds shouldn't be in the result set. What am I doing wrong?

```
select distinct 
a.ApplesID
, convert(varchar(10), a.FirstDate, 103) as 'FirstDate'
, convert(varchar(10), a.LastDate, 103) as 'LastDate'
, min(convert(varchar(10), o.Date, 103)) as 'FirstDT'
, max(convert(varchar(10), o.Date, 103)) as 'LastDT'
from Apples a with(nolock)
join Oranges o with(nolock)
    on o.ApplesID = a.ApplesID
where (o.Date between '01/01/2018' and '02/28/2019' and a.FirstDate >= '01/01/2018')
    and a.ApplesID > 0
    and a.Deleted = 0
group by a.ApplesID, a.FirstDate, a.LastDate
having (min(o.Date) <> a.FirstDate or max(o.Date) <> a.LastDate)
order by a.ApplesID
```

Comment: Hey joru100, Sample data, and desired output would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should have make it AND on the HAVING, instead of OR. The OR checks either of the filtering conditions... so the one making it true, and the one making for the other (or the other way round) will be accepted.

```
select distinct 
a.ApplesID
, convert(varchar(10), a.FirstDate, 103) as 'FirstDate'
, convert(varchar(10), a.LastDate, 103) as 'LastDate'
, min(convert(varchar(10), o.Date, 103)) as 'FirstDT'
, max(convert(varchar(10), o.Date, 103)) as 'LastDT'
from Apples a with(nolock)
join Oranges o with(nolock)
    on o.ApplesID = a.ApplesID
where (o.Date between '01/01/2018' and '02/28/2019' and a.FirstDate >= '01/01/2018')
    and a.ApplesID > 0
    and a.Deleted = 0
group by a.ApplesID, a.FirstDate, a.LastDate
having ((min(o.Date) <> a.FirstDate) AND (max(o.Date) <> a.LastDate))
order by a.ApplesID
```